# Add extra info to tooltip for specific bar in nvd3 multiBarChart

Tags: tooltip, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I use django with django-nvd3 to generate some charts. I'am not good in javascript at all.

I have this example (java script was created by django-nvd3)

http://jsfiddle.net/rkorzen/87WVr/2/

I want to add extra info to tooltip (if this extra info exist for my bar).

Data is composed of the blocks:

```
{"values": [{"y": 19, "x": "Checkpoint 1", "info":"ABDG"},
    {"y": 17, "x": "Checkpoint 2"}],
 "key": "Very good", "yAxis": "1"
},
```

in this point I want to ad info "ABDG" to tooltip for bar x="Checkpoint 1" and y=19
But don't have idea how :(

I'am not sure if django-nvd3 have some options for this. So decided to ask about js.
Maybe someone Can help:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using extra dict :

```
'chartdata': {    
              'x' : 'your_x_axis data',
              'name1': 'Somename',
              'y1': 'y_axis_data' ,
              'extra1': {
                        "tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"},                               
                         },
             }
```